# GCP Custom Images Additional Data

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, clone

My question is when you create a custom image (not a machine one) based on a boot disk source of a VM instance, do the apps installed, directories created, etc. present in that custom image? Or just the configuration of the boot disk? In other words, if I have a machine with installed apps on it and I want to create a second one using a custom image will my files/apps remain on the newly created VM instance?

I cannot find enough information in the Google documentation. I'm sure it works with machine images. I've tried to SSH to my instance and test it by myself, but I bump into other port problems that block me from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-custom) are ideal for situations where you have created and modified a persistent boot disk or specific image to a certain state and need to save that state for creating VMs.

Alternatively, you can maximize our [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) feature for the same purpose as well.